# Отправка COM-порт ASCII команд

Tags: c#, rs232, com-port

Задача в опросе весов CAS AP через RS 232 или СОМ порт.

1. Формат данных ASCII;
2. отправляем на весы запрос = "ENQ" -> 05H
3. получаем ответ = "ACK" -> 06H
4. отправляем на весы запрос = "DC1" -> 11H или "DC2" -> 12H
5. получаем ответ

Как отправить команду, поскольку что ENQ, что DC1 или DC2 не имеют символьного аналога? Может у кого есть соображения как отправлять ASCII команды, используя коды символов.

---

Теоретически это должно быть так:

```
int value = ??? ENQ
char c = Convert.ToChar(value);
byte[] mes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByte(new byte[] { c });
```

Или как вариант можно было бы и так:

```
string comand = "???";
byte[] mes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(comand);
```

Ну и:

```
_serialPort.Write(mes, 0, mes.Length);
```

Comment: А просто байты во отправлять умеете?

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ. Если есть вопросы, то задавайте - разберемся

Answer (score 1):

Отправлять следует байты, найдете в таблице ASCII:

```
someSerialPort.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
```

Описание функции смотрите на MSDN: [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx)

Для какой-то обработки принятых данных надо присоединить Ваш метод к событию `DataReceived`

Например:

```
_port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SomeMethod);
...
public void SomeMethod(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var receivedBytes = _someSerialPort.Read();
}
```

Примерная реализация метода `Read()`:

```
public byte[] Read()
{
    var buffer = new byte[_someSerialPort.BytesToRead];

    _someSerialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    return buffer;
}
```

На MSDN хорошо описаны методы, рекомендую к ознакомлению: [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

P.S. я в своем рабочем проекте реализовывал классы для работы с COM-портом, некоторая информация может быть Вам будет полезна: [ссылка на github](https://github.com/hitryy/TechMedServer/tree/master/TechMed/Connection)

Comment: А зачем ASCII, если значения байтов и так известны?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в заголовке "Отправка COM-порт ASCII команд" сказано...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов но в моем ответе ему (автору) надо будет просто создать массив байтов, которые ему нужны (а откуда, как и где будет брать - не имеет значения)